# How to avoid "undefined" value as an output?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am working on the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdugert/oc8ewdk6/)
When pasting an empty column in this code i get an undefined value,I am trying to convert this to '' (value='')
As an easy example, with columns separated by tabs
dateaccount debit credit in this attached image:
[image: screenshot undefined values]

I have tried to include a test

```
if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined') ...
```

with no luck 
how can this be done?
JS looks as follow:

```
  $(document).on('paste', 'textarea#excelPasteBox', function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var cb;
                  var clipText = '';
                  if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
                    cb = window.clipboardData;
                    clipText = cb.getData('Text');
                  } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
                    cb = e.clipboardData;
                    clipText = cb.getData('text/plain');
                  } else {
                    cb = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
                    clipText = cb.getData('text/plain');
                  }
                  var clipRows = clipText.split('\n');
                  for (i = 0; i < clipRows.length; i++) {
                    clipRows[i] = clipRows[i].split('\t');
                  }
                  var jsonObj = [];
                  for (i = 0; i < clipRows.length - 1; i++) {
                    var item = {};
                    for (j = 0; j < clipRows[i].length; j++) {
                      if (clipRows[i][j] != '\r') {
                        if (clipRows[i][j].length !== 0) {
                          item[j] = clipRows[i][j];
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    jsonObj.push(item);
                  }
                  $('textarea#jsonDataDump').val('');
                  var tablePlaceHolder = document.getElementById('output');
                  tablePlaceHolder.innerHTML = '';
                  var table = document.createElement('table');
                  table.id = 'excelDataTable';
                  table.className = 'table';
                  var header = table.createTHead();
                  var row = header.insertRow(0);
                  var keys = [];
                  for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
                    var obj = jsonObj[i];
                    for (var j in obj) {
                      if ($.inArray(j, keys) == -1) {
                        keys.push(j);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  keys.forEach(function(value, index) {
                    var headerCell = document.createElement('th');
                    headerCell.innerHTML = '<div>' + value + '<\/div>';
```

Comment: could you move your code to a jsfiddle? so i can test first...

Comment: Try removing the quotes: `if (typeof myVar !== undefined){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all of your if logic with a an assignment as shown below.

```
var jsonObj = [];
for (i = 0; i < clipRows.length - 1; i++) {
  var item = {};
  for (j = 0; j < clipRows[i].length; j++) {
    item[j] = clipRows[i][j]
  }
  jsonObj.push(item);
}
```

Comment: sounds so obvious now that you gave me the solution. Congrats for this answer, thank you so much!

Comment: You could also simply remove the whole `if (clipRows[i][j].length !== 0)` if statement, but keep the `item[j] = clipRows[i][j]` part. You currently set `item[j] = clipRows[i][j]` if `clipRows[i][j]` isn't an empty string. Otherwise (in the case `clipRows[i][j]` is an empty string) you set `item[j] = ""`. So you might as well just set `item[j] = clipRows[i][j]` at all times.

Comment: I've updated my answer because I overlooked an issue with the very last row / column being undefined. It will still output undefined because there is no return to cause it to hit the original else block. @3limin4t0r was correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Logical OR operator, `||` to add value whenever a variable is `undefined`

```
item[j] = clipRows[i][j] || '';
```

```js
let tmp;
console.log(tmp);
console.log(tmp || "");
console.log(tmp || "--na--");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace undefined value with empty string or whatever you want easily. Basically you can add this following line

if( item[j]===undefined)  item[j]="no data"; // no data or what ever you want

```
  var jsonObj = [];
  for (i = 0; i < clipRows.length - 1; i++) {
    var item = {};
    for (j = 0; j < clipRows[i].length; j++) {
      if (clipRows[i][j] != '\r') {
        if (clipRows[i][j].length !== 0) {
          item[j] = clipRows[i][j];
        }
      }
      if( item[j]===undefined)  item[j]="no data";
    }
    jsonObj.push(item);
  }
```

hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen, i have fixed.